# "View" right click context menu entry is missing in all directories, except for those optimized as "Pictures", "Videos", or "Music"

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu, right-click

Is this normal? I have never noticed this before.

For context, I have recently been doing things a little differently with the way I organize my directories. I've been making use of Windows' "folder optimization" features. In particular, if you optimize the My Pictures folder as "Pictures" (found in the "Customize" tab of the folder properties) and then choose "Large Icons" as the default view for that folder, you can then go to Folder Options (View tab in the Windows File Explorer 'ribbon', then Options, then "Change folder and search options") and under the View tab click on "Apply to folders". Now all folders optimized as "Pictures" will display as "Large Icons". Likewise, if you make changes to the 'columns' displayed in the "Details" view (ie date modified, file size, video resolution, etc, etc) for a folder that is optimized as "Pictures", these changes will also take effect for all 'Pictures' folders.

This is a great way to optimize organization of files and saves me a lot of time previously spent adjusting the file explorer "tag/metadata columns" (what are these officially called btw?) for each folder that I frequently browse.

I mention this because my noticing that "view" was missing (outside of the Pictures, Videos, and Music folders) may coincide to roughly around the same time as when I started doing this.

I should probably add that the context entry I am referring to is the one you are SUPPOSED to get when you right click in "open space" within a folder (ie not clicking on anything within the folder, but the folder itself)

I just tested it further, and it does not appear to matter whether I have the view set to "details" or "large icons", view is missing regardless. The only thing that will make it reappear is "customizing" the folder for Pictures, Music, or Videos.

Comment: I'd [edit] the question and rework [formatting](https://superuser.com/help/formatting) as not only me resists to read through a lengthy unstructered text.

Comment: And in addition, please remove the profanities from your post ...